# Call react native method from native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

How can i call a react native function written in my react native app from iOS native screen.
For example : i have a getDetails() method written in React native .js file. I need to invoke this method in iOS native screen on button click. Can some one let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: you have native buttons that are not generated by reactjs but want to respond to their interaction? Why do you even have this situation?

Comment: I am working on a pet project where i am evaluating all the scenarios to know how to handle the communication between react native to iOS and vice versa..